# How to enlarge the border of a div than it's actual width?

Tags: html, css

I have a child div with content. The div has inner padding and some margin. Now I want it to have a border more than it's actual width. How can I do that? My code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div> 

.parent{
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.child{
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}

p{
  margin:0;
}
```

The current situation: 
[image]

But the output I needed:
[image]

Note that, I can't change the margin and padding. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you can't change the margin and padding? Can you atleast override them?

Comment: Your "needed" output has 0 left margin (*the text has also moved left*). Why you cannot change it?

Comment: I can't change the margin because it will break down the whole layout under it. The design was nested in such a way, that it can't be changed. If I avoid the margin changing, then I can avoid a lots of css changing as well. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `margin-left` property solve your problem :

```css
.parent{
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.child{
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}

p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to change margin and padding, you can use `after` pseudo element like this :

```css
.parent{
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.child{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.child::after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -10px;
}

p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't change `margin` or `padding` use pseudo-element `::after`

```css
.parent {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.child {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative
}

.child::after {
  content: "";
  left: -10px;
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem you're having is confronted when you [understand the box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). `border` applies to `padding` and not to `margin`. It should be easy to figure out once you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.parent{
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.child{
      margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.child:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -10px;
}
p{
  margin:0;
}
```